# In a category $C$, is Hom$(X, Y)$ the same as (or in bijection with) Hom$(Y, X)$?

Tags: category-theory

I want to understand the notion of an opposite category in a very specific case, say the category $Grp$ of groups with homomorphisms as morphisms.

In the opposite category of groups $Grp^\circ,$ for some $G$ and $G'$ in this category, the set Hom$_{Grp^\circ}(G, G')$ of morphisms between them is defined to be the set Hom$_{Grp}(G', G)$ of morphisms between $G'$ and $G$ in the category $Grp$ of groups. It is known that there exists a contravariant functor $$op: Grp \to Grp^\circ $$ defined to be the identity map. This means that the morphism $f \in Hom_{Grp}(G, G')$ will get mapped to itself. Hence, my question:

Given a group homomorphism $f: G \to G'$ between two groups $G$ and $G'$, how can we also think of $f$ as a map from $G'$ to $G$ since $f$ is not assumed to have an inverse?

This question was answered many times on this site, but every time it's about general categories. I would like to understand this idea in a particular case of the category of Groups and with homomorphisms as their morphisms. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: A group homomorphism $f\colon G\to G'$ is mapped to $f^\circ\colon G'\to G$, which is not a map but a formal symbol.

Comment: the opposite construction is formal and does not land back in the category of groups.

Comment: If it helps, you could think of $f:G\to G'$ in $\mathbf{Grp}$ as a triple $(f,G,G')$ and in $\mathbf{Grp}^{\mathrm{op}}$ as $(f,G',G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit like a Zen koan, but the answer is that we simply do what we say we're doing: we think of $f:G\to G'$ as a "map" between $G'$ and $G,$ and that is how we do it.

The key thing to be sure of is that "map", here, does not mean any kind of *function.* It's thus better to say "morphism" or "arrow" to emphasize that the concept is purely abstract and formal. To summarize again, we think of a homomorphism $f:G\to G'$ as an arrow $G'\to G$ by *reversing the order of the symbols on the page.* That's what we do, and there is no more meaning to it than that.